# OrientDB -- is there a way to find out which edge was traversed?

Tags: orientdb

I've been researching/looking around high and low for this,
but, could not find any leads. 
I'm thinking this is a limitation, but, I would like to be sure.

**Scenario (1):**
In this scenario, I've explicitly informed which edge I'd like to traverse through. Thus, I know who is attending the VPN-101 event.

```
orientdb {db=event}> select firstname from (traverse in('people_attending_event')  from (select from Event where name='VPN-101')) where @class='People';

0   |null  |Mohammed
1   |null  |Sed
2   |null  |Fob
```

**Scenario (2):**
In this scenario, I'd like to know which vertices are associated to the VPN-101 vertex, therefore I used **_in()** over here. The output provides me with 3 names, but, is there a way to know which specific edges were traversed to get the output?
In this example, I have only selected **firstname**, however even if I perform a **select ***, it does not tell me which edges were traversed to get the output, it just provides me with the attributes associated to the vertices.

```
orientdb {db=event}> select firstname from (traverse in()  from (select from Event where name='VPN-101')) where @class='People';

0   |null  |Mohammed
1   |null  |Sed
2   |null  |Fob
```

Is there anything  I can do to know what I am looking for?
I appreciate any insight or help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returns last 3 traversed edge(s) of TRAVERSE command:

```
SELECT traversedEdge(-1, 3) FROM ( TRAVERSE outE(), inV() from #34:3232 WHILE $depth <= 10 )
```

For more info, look at documentation: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Functions.html#traversededge.

Comment: Thanks Luca! Thanks helpful. Still tons to learn about OrientDB. Actually, I was hoping to get the People name along with the edges it traversed. I decided to create a standard edge, populated it with attributes and performed a "join". eg select callsign, out_relationship.attending as attending, out_relationship.mandatory as mandatory from (traverse in("relationship") from (select from Event where name="VPN-101")) where @class="People"